# Can't get CE_Lossless to work

Tags: image

Has anyone had a problem with CE_Lossless where it reports that jpegtran and jpegoptim aren't installed even though they are?

The template debugger reports:

> (0.344540 / 6.28MB)   ***  CE Lossless debug: It doesn't look like the jpegtran is available.
>
> (0.344585 / 6.28MB)   ***  CE Lossless debug: It doesn't look like the jpegoptim is available.

But if I check the server I see they are both present:

> $ which jpegtran jpegoptim 
>   /usr/bin/jpegtran /usr/bin/jpegoptim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was here http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/ce-lossless/viewthread/13794

I needed to set a config variable for the Linux path using

> $config['ce_lossless_linux_path'] = '/usr/bin/';